# Canceling Button AutoPostBack - Specifics of OnClientClick implementation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, submit

When using a standard asp:Button component, it is necessary to use the following technique to cancel an automatic postback (or make a postback conditionally):

- Specify the client-side operations via the Button.OnClientClick property;
- Implement a logic that returns a Boolean value that indicates whether or not a postback should performed.

The following does not cancel a postback (despite of the "OnClientClickHandler" method returns "false"):

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="OnClientClickHandler();" />

function OnClientClickHandler() {
    return false;
}
```

The following implementation does:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="return OnClientClickHandler();" />
```

It looks like that this behavior is caused by specifics of the JavaScript code scope. Anyway, I am interested in the low-level implementation details of this scenario.

Why doesn't the first implementation (where there is no "return" operator before the "OnClientClickHandler" method call) work?

Comment: Are you sure the Javascript runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you need to add `return` is because returning false from an event handler is the way to cancel the default behavior (in this case, submit the form).

Another way to do the same is executing `event.prefentDefault()`

`OnClientClick="OnClientClickHandler();"` would be equivalent to

```
function onclick(){
    OnClientClickHandler();
}
```

while `OnClientClick="return OnClientClickHandler();"` would be equivalent to

```
function onclick(){
    return OnClientClickHandler();
}
```

Do you see the difference? In the first case you're just executing the function, but returning nothing.

Comment: I see. But I return the result from the client-side method. Why should it be also necessary to use the "return" operation in the Button markup?

Answer (score 0):

from MSDN

> Use the OnClientClick property to specify additional client-side
>   script that executes when a Button control's Click event is raised.
>   The script that you specify for this property is rendered in the
>   Button control's OnClick attribute in addition to the control's
>   predefined client-side script.

and also it mentions like this [SubmitBehaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior)

> Use the UseSubmitBehavior property to specify whether a Button control
>   uses the client browser's submit mechanism or the ASP.NET postback
>   mechanism. By default the value of this property is true, causing the
>   Button control to use the browser's submit mechanism. If you specify
>   false, the ASP.NET page framework adds client-side script to the page
>   to post the form to the server.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="return OnClientClickHandler();" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

try like this

```
function CancelPostBack()
{
  return false;
}
```

c# code. in PageLoad event.

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick","return CancelPostBack();");
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question. Why doesn't the first implementation (where there is no "return" operator before the "OnClientClickHandler" method call) work?